How to pass a component and state value in React to render conditional data based on user selection?
I am working on a React project where I have two components, UserRules (Component A) and UserEmail (Component B). I need to pass the value of a state variable selectedVoucherOption from Component A to Component B so that I can render specific data in Component B based on the selected option.
Here’s what I am doing:
In UserRules (Component A), I’ve added Line A because I want to pass the value of selectedVoucherOption to Component B (UserEmail) to render the data conditionally based on the user's selection.
Component A:
function UserRules({ intl, home, dispatch }) {
  const [selectedVoucherOption, setSelectedVoucherOption] = useState(null);

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col xs={12}>
        <Label required>{intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.voucherOptions.header })}</Label>
        <Dropdown
          options={voucherOptions}
          placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.voucherOptions.placeholder })}
          onChange={(_evt, obj) => {
            setSelectedVoucherOption(obj);
            UserEmail; // Line A: Trying to pass the value here
          }}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}

Component B:
function UserEmail({ intl, onValueChange }) {
  // Logic based on selectedVoucherOption
  ...
}

Email.propTypes = {
  intl: intlShape.isRequired,
  onValueChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

The problem I’m facing is figuring out how to pass the selectedVoucherOption state from Component A to Component B (at Line A) in a way that Component B can conditionally render data based on this value.
What’s the best way to achieve this in React?

Rendering a component happens in the JSX, not in a function.  (Though a function can certainly be used to build JSX, but that function would have to build JSX and not simply reference a component function like you're attempting.)
For example:
<Dropdown
  options={voucherOptions}
  placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.voucherOptions.placeholder })}
  onChange={(_evt, obj) => {
    setSelectedOption(obj);
  }}
/>
<UserEmail />

Note the <UserEmail /> as a standalone element in the markup.  You can conditionally include it by wrapping it in a conditional expression.  For example:
<Dropdown
  options={voucherOptions}
  placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.voucherOptions.placeholder })}
  onChange={(_evt, obj) => {
    setSelectedOption(obj);
  }}
/>
{ someCondition ? <UserEmail /> : null }

Note that the JavaScript expression is wrapped in {} to indicate that it is an expression and not JSX markup.  Whatever condition you use as someCondition would determine whether the expression evaluates to <UserEmail /> or null.
If you want to pass a prop to it, you'd do that exactly like the props you're already passing to other components:
<Dropdown
  options={voucherOptions}
  placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.voucherOptions.placeholder })}
  onChange={(_evt, obj) => {
    setSelectedOption(obj);
  }}
/>
{ someCondition ? <UserEmail someProp={selectedVoucherOption} /> : null }

And in the component you'd read that prop:
function UserEmail({ intl, onValueChange, someProp }) {
  // Logic based on someProp
}

Basically, the component you write is structurally no different from the 3rd party components you're already using.  A component is a component either way.  You'd include it in the JSX, conditionally or otherwise, and pass props to it like any other component.

Thanks, David, it looks great. I am wondering what you are trying to achieve by using the someCondition expression. The reason why I am using the UserEmail component inside the UserRules component is so that I can pass the value of the state variables from the UserRules component into the UserEmail component.

@flash: The someCondition expression conditionally renders the component in the JSX.  The question wasn't entirely clear about that, but it sounded like you may want to conditionally include or not include a component in your JSX.  If that isn't the case then you can disregard logic which conditionally includes or doesn't include a component in the JSX.

Sounds good. I've integrated the code inside fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fa5p4jcm/. Now at Line X, I am getting an error onValueChange is not a function.

@flash: What fiddle?  What is Line X?  Where do you call onValueChange?  Why specifically do you expect it to be a function?  If you have some new code which is failing in some new way, you can also ask a new question.

@flash: Regarding the edited comment... Please see Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.

I recommend you to go read the react docs. That is not how components are used.
What you want is probably something like this:


function UserRules({ intl, home, dispatch }) {
  const [selectedVoucherOption, setSelectedVoucherOption] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12}>
          <Label required>{intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.voucherOptions.header })}</Label>
          <Dropdown
            options={voucherOptions}
            placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.voucherOptions.placeholder })}
            onChange={(_evt, obj) => {
              setSelectedOption(obj);
            }}
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <UserEmail selectedVoucherOption={selectedVoucherOption} />
    </>
  )
  
  function UserEmail({ selectedVoucherOption }) {
    return (<span>{selectedVoucherOption}</span>)
  }




Thanks Samuel. Looks good. Appreciate your help on that. If you check UserEmail component definition, it has 3 parameters but in your definition you are using only 1.

Yeah, I simplified it. But you can just pass them as additional props, just like the selectedVoucherOption prop. For example, you can declare the onValueChange function on the parent component, pass it to the child component (UserEmail) as a new prop, and call it from the child component to trigger something on the parent.
